# OmniSharp ignoring #if / #endif blocks in Visual Studio Code (0.1.0 - 0.5.0)

Tags: intellisense, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

Several people at my studio are trying Visual Studio Code for Unity development on OSX, however all code within `#if`/`#endif` blocks is ignored by OmniSharp it seems like.

Within the `#if`/`#endif` block there is no intellisense, no "go to definition", no tracking of references, etc. As far as the rest of the OmniSharp features are concerned: the code within those blocks might as well not exist. Having no intellisense or "go to definition" gets to be bad enough that sometimes I have to switch IDEs when I'm writing code that is within `#if`/`#endif` blocks.

Is there something I can do to fix this? Is this something OmniSharp knows about already? I can't find anything through Google about this problem, so I feel like I'm the only one seeing it (along with everyone else on my project trying to use Visual Studio Code).

Answer (score 1):

I reported this same bug to VSCode and in response they moved it to OmniSharp's Github page; It is caused by OmniSharp's lack of support for MSBuild files, so it just ignores `<DefineConstants>` inside `.csproj` files. I think there has been some discussion about fixing this, but I have not seen any time-frame or work done.

I had to abandon using VSCode for the time being, since many plugins rely on those tags. I have been trying to find some other way to define those constants so that the editor would see them, but none of them have been fruitful yet.

Comment: The simplest "fix" for now would be for them to ignore all #if blocks entirely, at least then I'd get code completion, references, intellisense, etc, from within those blocks. Of course, I'm not sure how simple even that would be, there may be platform-specific code that wouldn't work properly if those #if blocks were ignored.

Comment: I had a little chat with the development team regarding Unity3D support and brought up this problem. Your "fix" is just what I tought would be the easiest way too. They are considering possible fixes and hopefully there will be some way around this in the next update. Though ignoring them could lead to conflicts on variable names and such.